# Como hago para relacionar atributos de un objeto a otro? Lenguaje Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo que asignar peliculas a clientes, ambos objetos de clases diferentes, la cantidad de objetos es indefinida ya que la pone el usuario y no tengo idea de como hacer para que se guarden las peliculas de cada cliente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinion, si entiendo el problema, deberias implementar un atributo a clientes que sea una ArrayList de objetos pelicula. Así podras asignar todas las peliculas que quieras.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).